# Install libbz2 from source on CentOS

Tags: centos, software-installation, compiling, libraries, bzip2

I want to install the bz2 library from ssh to my CentOS server.
I get it from [the homepage](http://bzip.org/downloads.html) and use

```
tar -xvf
```

command to extract it, but it does't have a `configure` file to compile and install it.

I need this library to install apt-get on CentOS and it needs this lib.
How can I install it? I'm accessing the machine over SSH.

Answer (score 1):

That archive does not contain a `configure` script, but it has a `Makefile` along with a `README` and a file called `README.COMPILATION.PROBLEMS`.

You should be able to do just

```
$ make
```

The output from doing that should tell you that everything went well and what to do next. If something fails, have a look in those READMEs.

Answer (score 0):

CentOS uses [`yum`](http://linux.die.net/man/8/yum) instead of `apt-get`. You can probably make `apt-get` work, but most of the docs and articles you find on the web are going to assume `yum`.

Comment: I want to install apt-get by yum.I get it apt-get source ,when I want to compile it ,it goes wrong because of libbz2 is not installed on server.

Comment: @Moein7tl I don't have a CentOS box in front of me, and I haven't tried these instructions before, but this article supposedly walks you through [installing `apt` using `yum`](http://www.wallpaperama.com/forums/how-to-install-apt-get-in-linux-instructions-installating-apt-redhat-fedora-t895.html). At a glance, it looks reasonable, but that's all I can say for it. I will say one more time that it probably makes more sense to just learn how to use `yum` than trying to manage a CentOS using `apt`, but you know your own needs best.